# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while updating the table in mysql

Tags: hibernate, jvm, out-of-memory

Trying to push/update large amount of collection into mysql using hibernate .My JVM heap size is 4GB still am facing OutOfMemoryError.Everything works fine when it call commit then error throws.

Note: I am new to hibernate.

Error :

> Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap
> space at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3745) at
> java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:172)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:748)
> at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:245) at
> com.mysql.cj.ClientPreparedQueryBindings.setString(ClientPreparedQueryBindings.java:651)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setString(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1752)
> at
> org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:46)
> at
> org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:73)
> at
> org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter$1.bind(AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.java:88)
> at
> org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:276)
> at
> org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:271)
> at
> org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:39)
> at
> org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3073)
> at
> org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3048)
> at
> org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister$2.bindValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3271)
> at
> org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
> at
> org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3279)
> at
> org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3885)
> at
> org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84)
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
> at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330)
> at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
> at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
> at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)
> at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
> at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:179)
> at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:100)
> at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$$Lambda$432/0x000000084074ac40.accept(Unknown
> Source)

Code:

```
public String addNewReport( int runId , Collection<ReportStorage> reportStorage )
    {
        int overAllCases = 0 ;
        int overAllPass  = 0 ;
        int overAllFail  = 0 ;
        try {
            if (isRunDetailExistsById(runId)) {
                
                HibernateConfig.getInstance().begin();
                RunDetails runDetails = HibernateConfig.getSession().get( RunDetails.class , runId);
                for( ReportStorage repStore : reportStorage )
                {
                    
                    repStore.setRun_id( runId );
                    repStore.getReportJson().setRun_id(runId);
                    overAllCases += repStore.getTotal_cases() ;
                    overAllPass  += repStore.getTotal_pass() ;
                    overAllFail  += repStore.getTotal_fail() ;
                }
                Collection<ReportStorage> existingReports = runDetails.getReports() ;
                existingReports.addAll( reportStorage ) ;
                runDetails.setReports( existingReports );
                runDetails.setEnd_time( CommonUtils.epocheTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date())) );
                String timetaken = CommonUtils.timeConverter(runDetails.getEnd_time() - runDetails.getStart_time() ) ;
                runDetails.setOver_all_cases( Integer.toString(overAllCases ) );
                runDetails.setOver_all_pasess( Integer.toString( overAllPass ) );
                runDetails.setOver_all_failures( Integer.toString( overAllFail ) );
                runDetails.setTotal_time_taken( timetaken );
                runDetails.setRun_status("SUCCESS");
                
                HibernateConfig.getSession().saveOrUpdate(runDetails);
                HibernateConfig.getInstance().commit();
                
                HibernateConfig.close();
                return "SUCCESS" ;
        }else {
            return "Run Id Mismatch" ;
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            REPORTREPOLOGGER.info("addNewReport-"+ e.toString() );
            HibernateConfig.getInstance().rollback();
            HibernateConfig.close();
            throw new CustomException("addNewReport" , e)  ;
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your origin data `runDetails` is too large.
when you execute `saveOrUpdate` function, it'll copy data first, but no more data memory left.

Here is my suggestion:

1. Try to increase the heap size of the JVM beyong the current 4GB if possible.
2. Another option cloud be batch the inserts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.Yes you are right ,runDetails is too large .If i increase my JVM beyond 4GB is good ??

Comment: Yes, It'll be useful if you can increase heap-size to large enough. But it can not be deal when a larger ```runDetails``` coming. So the most useful way is control the size of ```runDetails```, you can try batch-insert or just delete useless information in ```runDetails```. 

And by the way, why you need this so large data insert to database? It looks not like a normal way to process this kind of data, I mean, ```runDetails```  should be stroage in HBase or other else, not MySql.

Comment: runDetails contains our report .It contains collection of data.Now it is hard to switch to HBase from MySql .i'll try to implement batch insert as you suggested .